# discord.js - "TypeError: voiceChannel.join is not a function" while trying to make a bot join a voice channel

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots, voice

I've been trying to make my discord Bot join the voice channel of the person who has issued the command. I've been looking at other posts but wasn't really able to fix this problem.

```
D:\JS\Discordbot\commands\p.js:14
    const connection = await voiceChannel.join();
                                          ^

TypeError: voiceChannel.join is not a function
    at Object.module.exports.execute (D:\JS\Discordbot\commands\p.js:14:43)
    at Client.<anonymous> (D:\JS\Discordbot\main.js:33:34)
    at Client.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (D:\JS\Discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:18)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (D:\JS\Discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (D:\JS\Discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:345:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (D:\JS\Discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:443:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (D:\JS\Discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:300:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (D:\JS\Discordbot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:394:28)
```

Using following code for the command:

```
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const ytSearch = require('yt-search');

module.exports = {
    name: 'p',
    description: 'Joins + plays stuff'
}
module.exports.execute = async function (message, args){
    const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
    console.log(voiceChannel);
    if(!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('Not in a vc');
    if(!args.length) return message.channel.send('Invalid Input. Missing second argument.')

    const connection = await voiceChannel.join();

    const videoFinder = async (query) => {
        const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);

        return (videoResult.videos.length > 1) ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;
    }

    const video = await videoFinder(args.join(' '));

    if(video){
        const stream = ytdl(video.url, {filter: 'audioonly'})
        connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1})
        .on('fnish', () =>{
            voiceChannel.leave();
        });

        await message.reply(`Now Playing ***${video.title}***`)
    } else {
        message.channel.send('No results found.');
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: I'm currently using version 13.1.0

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's it. I was probably looking at older posts. Thank you very much!

Comment: You could give the answer an upvote if it answered your question (and it helps my reputation!)